# Displaying return values from iphlpapi.h (GetAdaptersInfo) with winforms (Converting from char* / wchar* to System::String)

Tags: c++, winforms, type-conversion

I'm having a problem using values from the returned struct of GetAdaptersInfo.
It returns a IP_ADAPTER_INFO struct (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_info) from which I take some values over into a custom struct.

**Minimal reproducible example:**

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <vector>
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")

struct Adapter_Info {
    DWORD ComboIndex;
    char* AdapterName;
    WCHAR* AdapterFriendlyName;
    char* Description;
    DWORD Index;
    char AdapterAddress;
    char* Type;
    char* CurrentIpAddress;
    IP_ADDR_STRING IpAddressList;
    char* GatewayList;
    bool DhcpServerStatus;
    char* DhcpServerStatusChar;
    char* DhcpServer;
};


#define MALLOC(x) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))
#define FREE(x) HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (x))

int main(std::vector<Adapter_Info>* p_retrieved_adapters, int* p_number_of_adapters)
{
    //creating returning vector and number_of_adapters
    std::vector<Adapter_Info> retrieved_adapters;
    int number_of_adapters = 0;

    /* Declare and initialize variables */
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo;
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapter = NULL;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;

    ULONG ulOutBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);
    pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO*)MALLOC(sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO));
    if (pAdapterInfo == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersinfo\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Make an initial call to GetAdaptersInfo to get
    // the necessary size into the ulOutBufLen variable
    if (GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
        FREE(pAdapterInfo);
        pAdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO*)MALLOC(ulOutBufLen);
        if (pAdapterInfo == NULL) {
            printf("Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersinfo\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    //call GetAdaptersInfo for counting number of adapters
    if ((dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen)) == NO_ERROR) {
        pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;

        //count number of adapters
        while (pAdapter) {
            number_of_adapters++;
            pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("GetAdaptersInfo failed with error: %d\n", dwRetVal);

    }

    //call GetAdaptersInfo again and retrieving the information for every adapter
    if ((dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen)) == NO_ERROR) {
        pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;

        //retrieve info for every adapter
        while (pAdapter) {

            Adapter_Info temp_adapter_info;

            temp_adapter_info.ComboIndex = pAdapter->ComboIndex;
            temp_adapter_info.AdapterName = pAdapter->AdapterName;
            //for testing purposes
            printf("\tAdapter Name: \t%s\n", pAdapter->AdapterName);
            printf("\tAdapter Name: \t%s\n", temp_adapter_info.AdapterName);
            temp_adapter_info.Description = pAdapter->Description;
            //for testing purposes
            printf("\tAdapter Desc: \t%s\n", pAdapter->Description);
            printf("\tAdapter Desc: \t%s\n", temp_adapter_info.Description);
            temp_adapter_info.Index = pAdapter->Index;

            retrieved_adapters.push_back(temp_adapter_info);
            pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;
        }
    }

    else {
        printf("GetAdaptersInfo failed with error: %d\n", dwRetVal);

    }

*p_retrieved_adapters = retrieved_adapters;
*p_number_of_adapters = number_of_adapters;

//free memory
if (pAdapterInfo)
    FREE(pAdapterInfo);
if (pAddresses) {
    FREE(pAddresses);
}

return 0;
}
```

**Use of main() in Form1.h:**

```
    std::vector<Adapter_Info> retrieved_adapters;
    std::vector<Adapter_Info>* p_retrieved_adapters = &retrieved_adapters;;

    int number_of_adapters;
    int* p_number_of_adapters = &number_of_adapters;

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
           main(p_retrieved_adapters, p_number_of_adapters);
                for (int xr = 0; xr < number_of_adapters; xr++) {
                     printf("\tAdapter Name: \t%s\n", retrieved_adapters[xr].AdapterName);
                     printf("\tAdapter Desc: \t%s\n", retrieved_adapters[xr].Description);
                 }

            String^ str0_0 = WcharToSysString(retrieved_adapters[0].AdapterFriendlyName);
            String^ str0_2 = CharToSysString(retrieved_adapters[0].Description);
    }
```

To display those values in labels with winforms I need to convert them over into System::String^.
For those purpose i created some conversion functions.

```
//wchar_t* to char
char* WcharToChar(wchar_t* wcharStr)
{
    // Create a string of wide characters, display it, and then
   // use this string to create other types of strings.
    wchar_t* orig = wcharStr;
    std::wcout << orig << _T(" (wchar_t *)") << std::endl;

    // Convert the wchar_t string to a char* string. Record
    // the length of the original string and add 1 to it to
    // account for the terminating null character.
    size_t origsize = wcslen(orig) + 1;
    size_t convertedChars = 0;

    // Use a multibyte string to append the type of string
    // to the new string before displaying the result.
    char strConcat[] = " (char *)";
    size_t strConcatsize = (strlen(strConcat) + 1) * 2;

    // Allocate two bytes in the multibyte output string for every wide
    // character in the input string (including a wide character
    // null). Because a multibyte character can be one or two bytes,
    // you should allot two bytes for each character. Having extra
    // space for the new string is not an error, but having
    // insufficient space is a potential security problem.
    const size_t newsize = origsize * 2;
    // The new string will contain a converted copy of the original
    // string plus the type of string appended to it.
    char* nstring = new char[newsize + strConcatsize];

    // Put a copy of the converted string into nstring
    wcstombs_s(&convertedChars, nstring, newsize, orig, _TRUNCATE);
    // append the type of string to the new string.
    //_mbscat_s((unsigned char*)nstring, newsize + strConcatsize, (unsigned char*)strConcat);
    // Display the result.
    std::cout << nstring << std::endl;
    return nstring;
}


//wchar_t* to std::string
std::string WcharToStdStr(const wchar_t* s, char dfault, const std::locale& loc)
{
    std::ostringstream stm;

    while (*s != L'\0') {  //EV. HIER FEHLER
        stm << std::use_facet< std::ctype<wchar_t> >(loc).narrow(*s++, dfault);
    }
    return stm.str();
}

//char* to std::string
std::string CharToStdStr(char* charStr)
{
    std::string stdStr(charStr);
    return stdStr;
}

//std::string to System::String^
System::String^ StdStrToSysString(std::string stdStr)
{
    System::String^ sysStr = gcnew System::String(stdStr.c_str());
    return sysStr;
}

//wchar_t* to System::String^
System::String^ WcharToSysString(const wchar_t* wcharStr)
{
    System::String^ sysStr = gcnew System::String(WcharToStdStr(wcharStr).c_str());
    return sysStr;
}

//char* to System::String^
System::String^ CharToSysString(char* charStr)
{
    System::String^ sysStr = gcnew System::String(CharToStdStr(charStr).c_str());
    return sysStr;
}
```

Sometimes those functions won't work at all. In some occasions they won't work at the first try and then start working after one more call to the GetAdaptersInfo function.

I only have problems with `AdapterFriendlyName` and `Description` from my custom struct.

I would appreciate any hint (Especially if there is a better way to manage those values, to display them with Winforms, without converting them).

Comment: First, `GetAdaptersInfo()` is *OLD*, use `GetAdaptersAddresses()` instead. Second, see [How to: Convert Standard String to System::String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-convert-standard-string-to-system-string?view=vs-2019). A `System::String` can be *directly* constructed from a C style `char*` or `wchar_t*` string, which you already know since you are already using those constructors. However, there is no need for `WcharToSysString()` to call `WcharToStdStr()`, or for `CharToSysString()` to call `CharToStdStr()`, that is unnecessary and redundant processing.

Comment: `System::String^ WcharToSysString(const wchar_t* wcharStr) { return gcnew System::String(wcharStr); }` `System::String^ CharToSysString(const char* charStr) { return gcnew System::String(charStr); }`

Comment: Also, you did not show how you are copying values from `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` to your own struct.  The use of raw pointers is worrisome if you are not managing memory correctly. Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] demonstrating how you are using that struct with `GetAdaptersInfo()`. Bad memory management could easily account for the problem you are seeing. Why does your custom struct use raw pointers at all rather than using `std::(w)string`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I got very confused dealing with all those types, but your answer shed a little light into the darkness :)

Question edited to include minimal reproducible example

Comment: @RemyLebeau
But even with my updated conversion functions I still receive some 'random' output in my labels at the first call.
One the second call they seem to be working just fine.

Question edited to include minimal reproducible example to use with C++ without Winforms/CLI

Comment: You did not show how you are using `main()`, but you are leaking memory like crazy inside of it. You are not freeing the `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` struct at all, and you are simply storing pointers to the `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` fields rather than making copies of the data. You really should get rid of your over-abundance of pointers. You are also not using `GetAdaptersInfo()` correctly in general.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I thought about my problem with the pointer I am storing into `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` fields, but right now I am quite confused on how to store the data itself into it.
And whats the point about the use of `GetAdaptersInfo()` in general? How is the right way of using those methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are leaking memory like crazy inside of your `main()` function. You are not freeing the `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` struct at all, and you are simply storing pointers to the `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` fields rather than making copies of the data. You really should get rid of your over-abundance of pointers.

You are also not really using `GetAdaptersInfo()` correctly in general.  You are calling it too many times.  It is one thing to call it to pre-calculate a buffer size, but once you have the actual data, stop calling it!  Right now, you are calling it to preallocate the buffer, then calling it again to get the actual data, and then you are calling again to get the data again (which is not guaranteed to be consistent the second time around!).

Try something more like this, using more C++-ish semantics than C-ish semantics:

```cpp
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <new>

#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")

struct Adapter_Info {
    DWORD ComboIndex;
    std::string AdapterName;
    std::wstring AdapterFriendlyName;
    std::string Description;
    DWORD Index;
    std::string AdapterAddress;
    std::string Type;
    std::string CurrentIpAddress;
    std::vector<std::string> IpAddressList;
    std::vector<std::string> GatewayList;
    bool DhcpServerStatus;
    std::string DhcpServerStatusChar;
    std::vector<std::string> DhcpServer;
};

int getAdapters(std::vector<Adapter_Info>& retrieved_adapters)
{
    std::vector<BYTE> buffer;
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
    ULONG ulOutBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO) * 5;

    //call GetAdaptersInfo to retrieve the information for every adapter
    do {
        try {
            buffer.resize(ulOutBufLen);
        }
        catch (const std::bad_alloc &) {
            std::cerr << "Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersInfo\n";
            return -1;
        }

        pAdapterInfo = reinterpret_cast<IP_ADAPTER_INFO*>(&buffer[0]);

        dwRetVal = GetAdaptersInfo(pAdapterInfo, &ulOutBufLen);
        if (dwRetVal == ERROR_NO_DATA)
            return 0;
    }
    while (dwRetVal == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW);

    if (dwRetVal != NO_ERROR) {
        std::cerr << "GetAdaptersInfo failed with error: " << dwRetVal << "\n";
        return -1;
    }

    //retrieve info for every adapter
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;
    int number_of_adapters = 0;

    do {
        Adapter_Info temp_adapter_info;

        temp_adapter_info.ComboIndex = pAdapter->ComboIndex;
        temp_adapter_info.AdapterName = pAdapter->AdapterName;
        //for testing purposes
        std::cout << "\tAdapter Name: \t" << pAdapter->AdapterName << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tAdapter Name: \t" << temp_adapter_info.AdapterName << "\n";
        temp_adapter_info.Description = pAdapter->Description;
        //for testing purposes
        std::cout << "\tAdapter Desc: \t" << pAdapter->Description << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tAdapter Desc: \t" << temp_adapter_info.Description << "\n";
        temp_adapter_info.Index = pAdapter->Index;

        retrieved_adapters.push_back(temp_adapter_info);
        pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;
    }
    while (pAdapter);

    return number_of_adapters;
}
```

```cpp
std::vector<Adapter_Info> retrieved_adapters;
int number_of_adapters;

private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    getAdapters(retrieved_adapters);
    if (!retrieved_adapters.empty()) {
        for (size_t xr = 0; xr < retrieved_adapters.size(); xr++) {
            std::cout << "\tAdapter Name: \t" << retrieved_adapters[xr].AdapterName << "\n";
            std::cout << "\tAdapter Desc: \t" << retrieved_adapters[xr].Description << "\n";
        }

        String^ str0_0 = StdWStrToSysString(retrieved_adapters[0].AdapterFriendlyName);
        String^ str0_2 = StdStrToSysString(retrieved_adapters[0].Description);
    }
}
```

You can add this to your helpers:

```cpp
//std::wstring to System::String^
System::String^ StdWStrToSysString(const std::wstring &stdStr)
{
    System::String^ sysStr = gcnew System::String(stdStr.c_str());
    return sysStr;
}
```

Comment: Retrieving IP addresses remains a miracle, pAdapter->CurrentIpAddress always zero?

Comment: @SamGinrich "*pAdapter->CurrentIpAddress always zero*" - it usually is. And the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_info) even says that `CurrentIpAddress` is "reserved", so you should not use it at all. You need to instead loop through `pAdapter->IpAddressList`, as an adapter can have more than 1 IP assigned to it.

Comment: Just found this, Thank you! They come as 0-terminated Strings