broadcast addresses for all local netowk interfaces AND their prefix lengths
I know that question about broadcast address was many times discussed. But I did not find any, when the answer considered netmask prefix length in the calculation of broadcast address.
All answers give the code that ends up with something like x.x.x.255 and all happy, but, as we know from here https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Network-and-Broadcast-Address, 255 is not always correct. F.E. the broadcast must be calculated using the netmask prefix length
So what I do if use boost asio:

get list of all local interfaces using tcp::resolver::query

loop over the tcp::resolver::iterator
2.1 - extract IP from endpoint
2.2 - need to do something, to determine REAL broadcast address of the network the interface connected to!


    std::set<std::string> interfaces;

    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
    boost::asio::io_service service;
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    tcp::resolver::query resolver_query(tcp::v4(), hostname(), "", tcp::resolver::query::numeric_service);
    tcp::resolver resolver(service);
    tcp::resolver::iterator it = resolver.resolve(resolver_query, ec);

    if (ec)
    {
        //std::cout << "Failed to resolve a DNS name." << "Error code = " << ec.value() << ". Message = " << ec.message();
        return interfaces;
    }

    tcp::resolver::iterator it_end;

    typedef boost::asio::ip::address_v4 A;
    // loop over iterator 
    for (; it != it_end; ++it)
    {       
        auto addr = it->endpoint().address();

        // case A: returns something like x.x.x.255
        auto broadcast = A::broadcast(addr, A::netmask(addr))

        //case B: returns always 255.255.255.255
        //auto broadcast = A::netmask(add).broadcast().to_str();
         
        interfaces.emplace(broadcast.to_string());
    }

The code above works only in case A, and only if the IP address of the interface (endpoint in the loop) is x.x.x.x/24.
In cases when the prefix length is f.e. /25, the calculated broadcast address is wrong (as it still ends with 255), and broadcast messages sent to it do not reach the nodes.
I know there is a class network_v4 in boost asio, that has prefix_length() getter, but to create an instance of network_v4 I need to pass the known prefix length into the constructor, so this seems like egg-chicken dilemma.
Is there any way to get the correct broadcast address for every local interface using the prefix length of the network it connected to? The resolver does not seem to be able to give me something more other than just endpoints with their addresses.
UPD. After some research I found that boost::asio does not provide proper address for subnets different from /24.

I don't know if there is a solution in boost, but most platforms provide an API that can report the actual broadcast address of each adapter/interface (or at least the subnet mask), eg getifaddrs() on 'Nix, GetAdaptersAddresses()+IPv4MaskLengthToString()+GetIpAddrTable() on Windows, etc.

To someone who also searching for a solution: WIndows https://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancediphelperfunction13g.html and Linux https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146999/how-do-i-read-the-subnet-mask-from-getifaddr but under linux you need to manipulate with mask according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address

getifaddrs() gives you the broadcast address in the ifu_broadaddr field if the IFF_BROADCAST flag in enabled in the ifa_flags field.

Unfortunatelly I cannot find field ifu_broadaddr in struct ifaddrs*. getifaddrs() returns me correct array of interfaces, but every element in it has only ifa_addr, ifa_data, ifa_flags, ifa_ifu, ifa_name, ifa_netmask, ifa_next.

ifu_broadaddr is a sub field of ifa_ifu. Read the documentation: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html

@RemyLebeau thank you! The answer updated accordingly.

The solution below was build after some research on the subject. Boost asio not able to provide proper broadcast address for networks different from /24. So the code below reaches the goal for windows using GetIpAddrTable() and linux using getifaddrs(). It was checked in local network with different prefixes.
#ifdef WIN32
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")
#endif

#ifdef __unix__
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#endif

std::string bipaddress(const std::string& interface)
{
    std::string result{ "" };
#ifdef WIN32

    auto inet_n2a = [](uint32_t addr, char* ipbuf)
    {
        sprintf(ipbuf, "%li.%li.%li.%li", (addr >> 24) & 0xFF, (addr >> 16) & 0xFF, (addr >> 8) & 0xFF, (addr >> 0) & 0xFF);
    };

    PMIB_IPADDRTABLE p_ip_table;
    DWORD dw_size = 0;
    p_ip_table = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE*)malloc(sizeof(MIB_IPADDRTABLE));
    if (p_ip_table)
    {
        if (GetIpAddrTable(p_ip_table, &dw_size, 0) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            free(p_ip_table);
            p_ip_table = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE*)malloc(dw_size);
            if (p_ip_table == NULL)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        return result;

    DWORD dw_ret_val = 0;
    LPVOID lp_msg_buf = nullptr;
    if ((dw_ret_val = GetIpAddrTable(p_ip_table, &dw_size, 0)) != NO_ERROR)
    {
        if (FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, dw_ret_val,
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            (LPTSTR)&lp_msg_buf, 0, NULL))
        {
            LocalFree(lp_msg_buf);
        }
        return result;
    }

    IN_ADDR ip_addr{};
    IN_ADDR mask_addr{};
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)p_ip_table->dwNumEntries; i++)
    {
        ip_addr.S_un.S_addr = ntohl((u_long)p_ip_table->table[i].dwAddr);
        char ifa_addr_str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]{ 0 };
        inet_n2a(ip_addr.S_un.S_addr, ifa_addr_str);

        mask_addr.S_un.S_addr = ntohl((u_long)p_ip_table->table[i].dwMask);

        uint32_t baddr = ip_addr.S_un.S_addr & mask_addr.S_un.S_addr;
        if (p_ip_table->table[i].dwBCastAddr)
            baddr |= ~mask_addr.S_un.S_addr;
        char dst_addr_str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN]{ 0 };
        inet_n2a(baddr, dst_addr_str);

        if (ifa_addr_str == interface)
        {
            result = dst_addr_str;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (p_ip_table)
    {
        free(p_ip_table);
        p_ip_table = nullptr;
    }

#else
    struct ifaddrs* ifas;
    if (getifaddrs(&ifas) == -1)
    {
        return "";
    }

    for (struct ifaddrs *ifa = ifas; ifa != nullptr; ifa = ifa->ifa_next)
    {
        if (!ifa->ifa_addr)
            continue;

        int family = ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family;
        if (family == AF_INET)
        {
            char host[NI_MAXHOST]{ 0 };
            getnameinfo(ifa->ifa_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in), host, NI_MAXHOST, 0, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
            if (interface == host)
            {
                if (ifa->ifa_flags & IFF_BROADCAST)
                {
                    char dst_buffer[NI_MAXHOST]{0};
                    unsigned int dst = ((struct sockaddr_in *)(ifa->ifa_ifu.ifu_broadaddr))->sin_addr.s_addr;
                    inet_ntop(family, &dst, dst_buffer, NI_MAXHOST);
                    result = dst_buffer;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(ifas);
#endif
    return result;
}


checked on local network with prefixes 24 , 25, 27 between linux and windows machines. All works fine.

Please don't throw a huge blob of code at the reades. Explain what the problem was with the OP, what the idea is to solve, and where in you code it can be seen.

ok, but I just followed general approach here on stackoverflow. What is different in my answer from ones here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60193128/displaying-return-values-from-iphlpapi-h-getadaptersinfo-with-winforms-conver or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100761/obtaining-subnetmask-in-c etc. ? Or you mean a comment must follow? Ok, added some on top of the message. Thanks

ahh you are right. Will try update both the question and the answer.

@DmitryGorelov on Linux, make sure you test to see if ifa->ifa_flags has the IFF_BROADCAST flag before accessing the ifa->ifa_ifu.ifu_broadaddr field
